# I try to convert date format in sql but it still doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the CONVERT() function to trying convert the date format like DD/MM/YYYY with code 103 when I query database, and nothing happens. The data field still displays default format with YYYY/MM/DD.

[image]

```
UPDATE STAFF
SET BIRTH = CONVERT(smalldatetime,'26/08/1900',103)
WHERE ID = 'SF01'
```

How can I fix this problem ? I'm a newbie so i don't know lots of SQL

Comment: What data type is the `smalldatetime` column please

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, what are you *actually* using?

Comment: If this is SQL Server, `smalldatetime` *is* the data type, @RiggsFolly . [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)'s parameters are Data Type, expression[, Style]. If it's MySQL, then the syntax isn't valid as according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) MySQL's implementation only has 2 parameters at most: expression and (data) type.

Comment: Please TAG only the DBMS you are actually using

Comment: The client tool decides how your date is shown. What client tool are you using?

Comment: Honestly I would save the date as is, and format it when you take it out of the database to display somewhere.

Comment: I definite BIRTH is SMALLDATETIME and I use the same date type in convert() function

Comment: I actually use SQL server.

Comment: So, as mentioned, the format the value is **presented** to the end user should be defined in the *presentation* layer, @Cherr._. . This isn't a task for your SQL layer, and you can't store a date (and time) value in a format (in SQL Server); they are stored as binary values and are "formatless".

Comment: @Larnu I know that. I mean, how to store default date format is DD/MM/YYYY such as 14/11/2022, 30/11/2022 when I query the date. I want the date show

Comment: Do you mean the default format that a literal string is interpreted in, @Cherr._. ? That's controlled by the `LOGIN`'s language setting, and can be explicitly defined for a connection using `SET DATEFORMAT`.

Comment: @Larnu You're a lifesaver, that's what I mean.

Answer (score -2):

Avoid formatting dates in your database, it should be done in the application that queries the data. But IF you still need to do it in your database for whatever reason:

If you want to store the date in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format in your table then you can do 2 things,

Change your column data type to `varchar`(**not ideal and you should try avoiding this method**)

Change the regional settings on the machine running SqlServer and keep it as a `date` type (this is somewhat useless if you plan on querying data from another app as the app will probably format the date to its local format).

In case you decide to store it as `varchar` you will need to use the `Format` function when inserting or updating like this: `Format(MyDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`.

Comment: `FORMAT` is a terribly *slow* function, and suggesting to store date (and time) data in the database as a `varchar` is a *terrible* idea. `'19/01/2022'` is **before** `'21/12/1997'` not *after*, for example. If the format the date (and time) value is *presented* in is important then that is a task for the presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: When I search google, I catch lots of webs use varchar as data type to solve my problem.

Comment: I have not said it is an ideal way to do what OP asked. I just said it can be done in that way. I will edit my answer to avoid any confusion over this